# Display Contents of Log files on JSP page dynamically

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, logging, servlet-3.0

I have made dynamic web project where i want to display my log files in a gui view  on a jsp page so that admin can monitor his application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice Question, Have you tried [Apache FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) and [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29)? Read the log file and store in a String/List is possible here. So you can display the log in your jsp page.

Comment: Thanx for giving the answer but I am not using apache server. I am using JBoss server.Is there any API just like in apache so that i can read log files

Comment: Apache Tomcat server and Apache FileUtils are different. You got confused. You can use whatever server you want. All you need to do is import this line `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` or add commons jar file which have the FileUtils class.

Comment: @ShekharSaxena You are welcome. Mark this as answer if it helped you. May be others will get the benefit from this.